# Accidentally removed /usr/local/ directory. Now what?

Tags: reboot

I accidentally  removed /usr/local/ directory. I have not reboot or anything. I am now root.

Do I have to install ubuntu again or just create a new user?

Thanks.

Comment: What was the command? `rm` or `rm -r`? if `rm`: `/usr/local/` should only have directories so it should not have deleted anything ;)

Comment: rm -rf /usr/local/

Comment: Here is a list of the directories that where in /usr/local/: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've just removed `/usr/local`, it is not critical. That directory is intended for local installations (i.e. packages installed outside the package management system, APT). You do not need to recreate it, programs that need it are supposed to install it themselves.